# How do I stop overflow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am still new to coding, I have created multiple textbutton.icon's but they overflow. How do i stop the overflow. Even if i put is in a row or column it still overflows. I also would like to put more spacing between each row of buttons but that just makes it overflow more. Here is the multiple class code:

```
class home_buttons {
  List<Widget> jeffButtons = [
  Button1(),
  Button2(),
  Button3(),
  Button4(),
  Button5(),
  Button6(),
  Button7(),
  Button8(),
  Button9(),
];
}
```

Here is the button code:

```
class Button1 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: TextButton.icon(
        onPressed: () => {},
        icon: Column(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 75,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(
                'Contact Us',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        label: Text(
          '', //'Label',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter listview normally have undefined height. The total height of listview is defined based on the items in the list. So when you declare listview directly you get overflow issue.

So as a solution you need to specify the height for the outer container, or use sizedbox to define the height.

Specifying height will solve your issue of overflow. To provide space between buttons you can also wrap that in a container and use the benefit of margin or padding to handle it efficiently.

Please find this code snippet to use Media to find height of device

```
Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    color: Colors.white,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
```

Here instead of SingleChildScrollView You can use listview or listbuilder which will solve your overflow issue

Hope this helps. Let me know If you want more details. Thanks

Comment: that just makes it overflow more

Comment: You can use the container as outer, and for that give height using media query, and in the children, you can use Column, List view, or ListBuilder, which won't give you overflow error.
For your clear understanding, I have added a small code snippet, you can change it as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your widgets with the `SingleChildScrollView` to enable scrolling.

Or if you want to fit the screen inside a Column or Row Widget you can wrap individual widgets with a `Flexible` Widget